# Uncaught Error: Module name "@angular/core" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Tags: angularjs, angular

Can someone explain this ERROR, what it really means and what should be done in order to solve it? I'm have a module of @angular/core that need to be imported into angularJS app. I am trying to insert angular component into angularjs app, so this import the new component are requireed

This is the component.ts file (I took its js file and include it into angularjs app):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello-world',
  template: `
    <p>
      hello angular 2!
    </p>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class HelloWorldComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }


}

// Angular 1 Vendor Import
import * as angular from 'angular';

import { downgradeComponent } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive(
    'helloWorld',
    downgradeComponent({component: HelloWorldComponent}) as angular.IDirectiveFactory
  );
```

Comment: Have you added `import { Component } from "@angular/core";` on top of your component?

Comment: Yes, but I think I don't really understand how I'm importing @angular/core into angular 1 app

Comment: No you shouldn't. All you need in angular 1 is the reference to Angular.min.js (1) in your main layout